# Linux Mint MATE Caja “Share Folder…” menu entry missing

Tags: linux, linux-mint, file-sharing, mate

I have two Linux Mint 16 MATE boxes connected. One has the "Share Folder..." right-click menu item in Caja, and the other does not. How do I get it?

Later:

After installing `caja-share`, the menu item shows as `Sharing Options` rather than `Share Folder...` as on the other machine. Both are Linux Mint 16 w/ MATE and Caja version 1.6.2. What is the difference?

Also one machine already had access to the other before I started trying to share the other way. The share that is 'working' is listed in the `Location:` as `smb://pcname/user-pcname/` so it looks like a samba share. And the files' `owner`, `group` and `permissions` are all `unknown`.

When I try to put in a `smb://<etc>` location on the other machine, I get a login box that always rejects my password. The original connection that is open never asked for a password. I prefer not to have to put in a password all the time.

Very confused. Please help.

Comment: did you figure this out?  I also had the "Share Folder..." option in the past, and have a folder shared, but the option no longer exists.

Comment: maybe the original menu item was from having `nautilus-share` installed?  I installed `caja-share` and now there's a "Sharing Options" that does the same thing.